# Pinescript | MA for first n-1 values

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The classic N-period Moving Average script ignores the first N-1 values.
The built-in script is `ta.sma(price, length)`.

I would like to perform a calculation that doesn’t drop the first candles, in a fashion like `ta.sma(price, min(length, N))` where N is the location of the particular candle.

I am not experienced with referencing in pinescript, it is the first time I am experimenting with it.